# Can pass reference variable pointing to Lambda in Java

Tags: java, lambda, spring-reactive

I as trying out some Spring reactive code and following is relevant piece of code

```
Supplier<Stream<Long>> longStreamSupplier = ()
            -> LongStream.iterate(0,
                    nextLong -> nextLong + 1).boxed();

Flux<Long> fooIds = Flux.fromStream(longStreamSupplier);
```

Last line above gives compilation error in Intellj IDE saying there is not method which accepts the type.

However if i convert it to following :

```
Flux<Long> fooIds = Flux.fromStream(() -> LongStream
                    .iterate(0, nextLong -> nextLong + 1)
                    .boxed());
```

This works fine. Why it cant accept a reference variable pointing to the same lambda expression i am passing in second piece of code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because the `longStreamSupplier` variable has type `Y<X<A>>`, while the method expects an argument with type `Y<X<? extends A>>`, and these types aren't interchangeable.

**edit**

you can change the variable type to make the first example compile,

```
Supplier<Stream<? extends Long>> longStreamSupplier = ..
```

Answer (score 2):

Your argument type for `fromStream` is wrong in the first example.
In the second snippet it has been correctly deduced as `Supplier<Stream<? extends Long>>`, while in the first you explicitly "narrowed" it down to something that's not accepted by `Flux.streamOf`.

You could fix the first snippet by writing:

```
        Supplier<Stream<? extends Long>> longStreamSupplier = ()
                -> LongStream.iterate(0,
                nextLong -> nextLong + 1).boxed();

        Flux<Long> stream = Flux.fromStream(longStreamSupplier);
```

You might ask yourself

> Why isn't there an overload for this function which accepts explicitly `Supplier<Stream<T>>` instead of  `Supplier<Stream<? extends T>>`.

That's because of Java Type Erasure, consider the following two functions:

```
    private void foo(Supplier<Stream<? extends  Long>> stream) {

    }
    private void foo(Supplier<Stream<Long>> stream) {

    }
```

When compiling, after type erasure, we are left with:

```
    private void foo(Supplier stream) {

    }
    private void foo(Supplier stream) {

    }
```

Which produces a compile error, because we have two functions with identical definitions. So in the case of `Flux::fromStream`, the more flexible version is implemented.